# I can't access mounted volume of docker-postgres from host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I create my container like this:

```
docker run --name postgresql -itd --restart always \
--publish 5432:5432 \
--volume /my/local/host:/var/lib/postgresql \
sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-11
```

but, when I do `ls` on the root directory, I see something like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 messagebus messagebus 4,0K Ιαν  10 00:44 host/
```

or, in other words, I cannot access the `/my/local/host` directory. I have no idea about the `messagebus` user. is that normal? if this is the case, then how could I move the database from one machine to another in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a data container to hold your DB data. The pattern is described in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/) and is designed to promote clean separation between run-time and data.

```
$ docker create -v /var/lib/postgresql --name dbdata sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-11 
$ docker run --name postgresql1 -itd --restart always \
--publish 5432:5432 \
--volumes-from dbdata
sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-11
```

A separate data container makes backup and recovery simpler and more obvious

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql
```

---

The following posting I think gives a good explanation of data containers:

- https://medium.com/@ramangupta/why-docker-data-containers-are-good-589b3c6c749e#.zarkr5sxc